# How to provide dynamic className to element in React Class render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I have a ReactClass with name Alert. Its render method returns a div with class `alert alert-success` or `alert alert-error` according to the type passed while creating element. I just want to know how to add class based on the type of alert element.

Here is my attempt:

```
var Alert = ReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className="alert {this.props.type}">{this.props.message}</div>
  }
});

var successAlert = React.createElement(Alert, {
  type: 'alert-success'
  message: 'Information saved successfully!!'
});
```

When JSX Template is compiled `this.props.type` is not converted to the class passed to element. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Use `className` not `class`.

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs. It was a typo because I wrote the code in editor itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I have found answer to my question. We can simply do something like this:

```
var Alert = ReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className={"alert " + this.props.type}>{this.props.message}</div>
  }
});
```

Just put your classes inside Template evaluators `{ }` in this case. Create your class string based on your props and states.

Hope this is helpful to others.

Answer (score 4):

One way to accomplish this is to have a string which will contain all of your classes and then set it to the Component's `className`:

```
var Alert = ReactClass({

  var yourClassName = 'alert ';

  // Add any additional class names
  yourClassName += this.props.type + ' ';

  render: function() {
    return <div className={yourClassName}>{this.props.message}</div>
  }
});
```

or alternatively you can store your class names in an array and convert it to a class friendly string when you're ready to use it:

```
var Alert = ReactClass({

  var yourClassArray = [];

  // Add any additional class names
  yourClassArray.push('alert');
  yourClassArray.push(this.props.type);

  var classString = yourClassArray.join(' ');

  render: function() {
    return <div className={classString}>{this.props.message}</div>
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I knew this approach but this does not look very neat to me. Because most of the time your template logic contain conditions like if/else in className attribute. I am mostly handlebars user where it is so easy to achieve these things.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package. You can do stuff like this:

```
className={classNames('alert', `alert-${type}`)}
```

or

```
className={classNames({
    'alert': true,
    'alert-success': success,
    'alert-error': error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var Alert = ReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className={`alert ${this.props.type}`}>{this.props.message}</div>
  }
});
```

Your code can be written in following way:

```
const Alert = ({type, message}) =>
    <div className={`alert ${type}`}>{message}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Write in code**

```
className={`form-control-sm d-inline per_player ${"per_player_b_" + index + "_score"}`}
```

**and You will get**

[image]